# Upload Multiple Files to Server & Copy Path to DB

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to upload multiple photos of a new user to a new directory on the server, assigning a directory name for that person based in their name and ID in the DB. A path to the new directory is added to a field in the DB, so that these photos can be referenced later. All other DB functionality is working except for this.

I haven't worked on this project for a good 6 months, and this feature was working at some stage. I am unsure what I have messed up. At present I get '0 files uploaded successfully', with no new directory or reference being created. DB connection must be fine as other info earlier in the code not included here is adding without an issue.

Please help. I am pulling at what little hair I have left!

```
$count = 0;
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png");
$max_file_size = 1024*5000;
$lastID = $mysqli->insert_id;
$path = '../img/gallery/'.$lastID.'_'.$displayName.'/';
$path2 = './img/gallery/'.$lastID.'_'.$displayName.'/';

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    // Loop $_FILES to execute all files
    foreach ($_FILES['photoUploader']['name'] as $f => $name) {     
        if ($_FILES['photoUploader']['error'][$f] == 4) {
            continue; // Skip file if any error found
        }          
        if ($_FILES['photoUploader']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
            if ($_FILES['photoUploader']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                continue; // Skip large files
            }
            elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($displayName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                continue; // Skip invalid file formats
            }
            else { // No error found! 
                // Create new directory based on unique ID and display name
                if (!is_dir($path)) {
                    mkdir($path, 0777, true);       
                }
                // move temporary files to permanent location
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photoUploader"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name))
                $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
                // add image folder url to db for future use
                $imageUrlQuery = "UPDATE models SET photoLocation=? WHERE id=$lastID";
                $imageUrlstmt = $mysqli->prepare($imageUrlQuery);
                $imageUrlstmt->bind_param('s', $path2);
                $imageUrlstmt->execute();         
            }
        }
    }
    echo $count . " file(s) uploaded successfully!";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is going to seem stupid. It was a simple oversight.....

```
elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($displayName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                continue; // Skip invalid file formats
```

$displayName needed changing to $name. That was it. Sigh......

Answer (score 1):

Set form to:

```
  multipart/form-data
```

Cluster upload items: **photos[ ]**

```
 <input type="file" name="photos[]" multiple="multiple" id="multipic"/>
 <label for="multipic"><btn> Select 3 Photos </btn></label>
```

Handle Files

```
 foreach($_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
 $file_name = $_FILES['photos']['name'][$key];
 $file_tmp = $_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][$key];
 $file_size = $_FILES['photos']['size'][$key];

 $photo1="dir/where/photos/go/";
 $photo1=$photo1 . basename($_FILES['photos']['name'][0]);
 $fz1=$_FILES['photos']['size'][0];

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][0], $photo1)) {
 /* do whatever you like here */ }

 $photo2 ...
 $photo3 ...

 }
```

You can do this for each item: [0] [1] [2], etc.

Comment: most of this is handled in there. the main issue is really the referencing to the folder. all my issues stemmed from a incorrectly declared variable. but you nicely summed up what the process is. thanks!